# Entity Framework keeps data in memory even though it's disposed

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, memory, using

I'm currently playing a little bit with the EF since I want to use it in a new project but I came across a little memory problem which I cannot explain to myself.

The situation is the following:

I open a new form containing a grid which displays data. In the `OnLoad` event I get data from the database using the entity framework model:

```
   Using db As New OfficeDatabaseModelContainer(DatabaseManager.Instance.ProductiveConnectionString)
        Dim groupList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        groupList.Add("Active")
        GridUtils.AssignObjectListToGrid(grdUser, db.User, GetType(User), groupList)
   End Using
```

This code adds about 10MB to the memory (due to testing I read 15k rows from the database).
When I close the form I programmatically dispose the form as well as the grid containing the data. But the 10MB of the context of the database model stays in the memory. Even though it should be disposes as I got the data in a using block.

If I open the form 10 times it always adds the new amount of data to the memory (which makes sense) but doesn't clear the disposed data.

I even tried to call `GC.Collect()` while closing the form but it doesn't help either.

The memory leak doesn't come from the grid or something. I proved that using the following code:

```
Dim userList = DatabaseManager.Instance.ProductiveDatabase.User
Dim groupList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
groupList.Add("Active")
GridUtils.AssignObjectListToGrid(grdUser, userList, GetType(User), groupList)
```

This way I have a static property of the database model in a singleton class. Where the `ProductiveDatabase` is the instance of the model and the User represents the table User. I can call the form as often as I want the memory usage keeps at ~10MB which makes perfectly sense since I'm always using the same reference to the same objects this way.

There must be something I am doing wrong. I've searched the internet regarding the usage of the model and keeping the memory usage as low as possible. It seems the best practice here is using the using block while working with the model.

Comment: What happens in `AssignObjectListToGrid`, in particular: do you tie any events? And, did you investigate this with a memory profiler? Windows task manager is not the best tool to pin down memory problems. A memory profiler is recommendable anyway because it will show you the objects that stay in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I would dispose of the list after you are done with it in your code
in fact dispose of any object that is IDisposable

groupList.dispose

Comment: Basically that's what I am doing. The db model and its context should be disposed because it's inside the using block.

the groupList doesn't hold any data it's just a list of strings which tells the grid to group it self with the provided content.

The grid is disposed when the from is closing. As I wrote if I use the db model as a static property I have no memory problems.

Answer (score 0):

The first call to the dbcontext will build all of the configurations etc. and store this statically within the process memory. To confirm this try adding a 2nd and 3rd call and the memory footprint should remain consistent.